# How do I write my FK value in a different table? C# | SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, dapper

I'm working on a school project where I am creating a client management system.   Due to a requirement, I was required to change my database schema from using 1 table to using 2. Currently, I am able to write to both tables in my database, however, I am having trouble getting the concepts of foreign keys.  I have very limited SQL experience. My current execute statements are writing to both my tables except my the client ID column in the MedicalInformation table.  It is showing null and I'm not sure how I should proceed from here.

```
cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO ClientInformation (FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, Phone, Email, Address, City, State, Zip, DateOfBirth, Occupation, Employer, EmergencyContact, EmergencyContactRelationship, EmergencyContactPhone) " +
            "VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleInitial, @LastName, @Phone, @Email, @Address, @City, @State, @Zip, @DateOfBirth, @Occupation, @Employer, @EmergencyContact, @EmergencyContactRelationShip, @EmergencyContactPhone)", client);


cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO MedicalInformation (CurrentMedications, ChronicPain, ChronicPainWhere, OrthopedicPain, OrthopedicPainWhere, Pregnant, PreferedPressureLight, PreferedPressureMedium, PreferedPressureDeep, Allergies, AllergiesWhat, Cancer, HeadacheMigraine, Arthritis, Diabetes, JointReplacement, HighLowBloodPressure, Neuropathy, Fibromyalgia, Stroke, HeartAttack, KidneyDysfunction, BloodClots, Numbness, SprainsStrains, AreasOfDiscomfort) " +
            "VALUES (@CurrentMedication, @ChronicPain, @ChronicPainWhere, @OrthopedicPain, @OrthopedicPainWhere, @Pregnant, @PeferredPressureLight, @PeferredPressureMedium, @PeferredPressureDeep, @Allergies, @AllergiesWhat, @Cancer, @HeadacheMigraine, @Arthritis, @Diabetes, @JointReplacement, @HighLowBloodPressure, @Neuropathy, @Fibromyalgia, @Stroke, @HeartAttack, @KidneyDysfunction, @BloodClots, @Numbness, @SprainsStrains, @AreasOfDiscomfort) ", client.MedicalInfo);
```

This is a portion of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE "MedicalInformation" (
    "_ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Client_ID" INTEGER,
    
    PRIMARY KEY("_ID" AUTOINCREMENT),
    FOREIGN KEY("Client_ID") REFERENCES "ClientInformation"("Client_Id")
);

CREATE TABLE "ClientInformation" (
    "Client_Id" INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   
    PRIMARY KEY("Client_Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

My clientinfo class

```
public class ClientInformation
    {
        //Client Information
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Occupation { get; set; }
        public string Employer { get; set; }
        public string EmergencyContact { get; set; }
        public string EmergencyContactRelationship { get; set; }
        public string EmergencyContactPhone { get; set; }
        public MedicalInformation MedicalInfo { get; set; }
        public ClientInformation(string firstname, string middleinitial, string lastname, string phone, string email, string address, string city, string state, string zip, string dateofbirth, string occupation, string employer,
        string emergencycontact, string emergencycontactrelationship, string emergencycontactphone, MedicalInformation clientMedicainfo)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstname;
            this.MiddleInitial = middleinitial;
            this.LastName = lastname;
            this.Phone = phone;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Address = address;
            this.City = city;
            this.State = state;
            this.Zip = zip;
            this.DateOfBirth = dateofbirth;
            this.Occupation = occupation;
            this.Employer = employer;
            this.EmergencyContact = emergencycontact;
            this.EmergencyContactRelationship = emergencycontactrelationship;
            this.EmergencyContactPhone = emergencycontactphone;
            this.MedicalInfo = clientMedicainfo;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `ClientInformation.Client_Id` key is automatically generated by SQLite, you'll need to retrieve it somehow before inserting on the `MedicalInformation` table.

I'm not experienced with SQLite, but from a quick glance at the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid), I found out that you can use the `last_insert_rowid()` function to retrieve the ID of the last row insert.

You'll need this `Client_ID` value inside your `client.MedicalInfo` object for later processing, so I think it's possible to do something like this:

```cs
client.MedicalInfo.Client_ID = cnn.ExecuteScalar<int>("INSERT INTO ClientInformation (FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, Phone, Email, Address, City, State, Zip, DateOfBirth, Occupation, Employer, EmergencyContact, EmergencyContactRelationship, EmergencyContactPhone) " +
            "VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleInitial, @LastName, @Phone, @Email, @Address, @City, @State, @Zip, @DateOfBirth, @Occupation, @Employer, @EmergencyContact, @EmergencyContactRelationShip, @EmergencyContactPhone);" +
            "SELECT last_insert_rowid();", client);

cnn.Execute("INSERT INTO MedicalInformation (Client_ID, CurrentMedications, ChronicPain, ChronicPainWhere, OrthopedicPain, OrthopedicPainWhere, Pregnant, PreferedPressureLight, PreferedPressureMedium, PreferedPressureDeep, Allergies, AllergiesWhat, Cancer, HeadacheMigraine, Arthritis, Diabetes, JointReplacement, HighLowBloodPressure, Neuropathy, Fibromyalgia, Stroke, HeartAttack, KidneyDysfunction, BloodClots, Numbness, SprainsStrains, AreasOfDiscomfort) " +
            "VALUES (@Client_ID, @CurrentMedication, @ChronicPain, @ChronicPainWhere, @OrthopedicPain, @OrthopedicPainWhere, @Pregnant, @PeferredPressureLight, @PeferredPressureMedium, @PeferredPressureDeep, @Allergies, @AllergiesWhat, @Cancer, @HeadacheMigraine, @Arthritis, @Diabetes, @JointReplacement, @HighLowBloodPressure, @Neuropathy, @Fibromyalgia, @Stroke, @HeartAttack, @KidneyDysfunction, @BloodClots, @Numbness, @SprainsStrains, @AreasOfDiscomfort); ", client.MedicalInfo);
```

Just make sure the `client.MedicalInfo.Client_ID` property exists in your DTO class.

Comment: I have tried what you said and I am only getting 0s written to the database now

Comment: Try the second option. I'm not sure how SQLite works internally, but it's probably discarding the stored value of the first insert because you're running two separated Execute statements, so you'll need to store it in your object. I've removed the first option from my answer so you don't get confused

Comment: Same thing.  It's writing a 0.  I added my clientinfo class above

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your class structure. Since you're passing `client.MedicalInfo` as a parameter to the second insert, the return value of `ExecuteScalar` should be stored in a property inside your `MedicalInformation` class. You'll be assigning the return value of `ExecuteScalar` to `client.MedicalInfo.Client_ID` instead of `client.Client_ID`. I've updated my answer again. Tell me if it finally works now. :)

Comment: You helped me more than you know =)